# Read txt file into array then find min max and average of salaries

Tags: java, arrays

Looks like this is the week for this type of question. And after reading through all of the new ones and several old ones, I'm no less confused!

I have a text file with 5 employees, each having 10 salary values listed beneath their name. I am to read in this file, find and display the employee Name, minimum salary, maximum salary and the average salary for each person. I must have 3 loops: One to control reading the file, one to lad the data into the array, and one to do the calculations. I have to print the information for each person on one line, and i must allow decimals rounded to 2 decimal places apparently using `Math.round` which I've never heard of!

I am embarrassed to show you the mess of code I have because it's not much, but I don't know after reading all that I have if I've even started correctly.  I do not know if I have even the right idea of how to proceed.  Your help is appreciated.

**UPDATED CODE:** AGAIN!

```
    import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
public class MinMaxSalary3
{
    public static void main(String args[])throws Exception
    {
        // Declare input file to be opened.
        FileReader fr = new FileReader ("salary.dat");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (fr);
        //General Declarations
        final String TITLE = "Employee's Salary Report";
        String employeeName, salaryString;
        double avgSalary=0.0;
        double totalSalary = 0.0;
        double sum = 0.0; 
        // Declare Named Constant for Array.
        final int MAX_SAL = 10;     
        // Declare array here.
        int salary[] = new int[MAX_SAL];

         System.out.println (TITLE);
            while ((employeeName = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
               System.out.print ("" + employeeName);


        // Use this integer variable as your loop index.
                int loopIndex;                  
        // Assign the first element in the array to be the minimum and the maximum.
                double minSalary = salary[1];
               double maxSalary = salary[1]; 
        // Start out your total with the value of the first element in the array.
                sum = salary[1]; 
            // Write a loop here to access array values starting with number[1]
                for (loopIndex = 1; loopIndex < MAX_SAL ;loopIndex++)
        // Within the loop test for minimum and maximum salaries.
                {
                    if  (salary[loopIndex] < minSalary)
                    {
                        minSalary = salary[loopIndex];

                   if (salary[loopIndex] > maxSalary)

                    maxSalary = salary[loopIndex];


                    }   

                        {
            // Also accumulate a total of all salaries.
                       sum += sum; 
          // Calculate the average of the 10 salaries.
                            avgSalary = sum/MAX_SAL;
                        }
            //  I know I need to close the files, and end the while loop and any other loops. I just can't think that far right now. 
            }
            {
        // Print the maximum salary, minimum salary, and average salary.
            System.out.println ("Max Salary" + maxSalary);  
            System.out.println ("Min Salary" + minSalary); 
            System.out.println ("Avg Salary" + avgSalary); 
            }


        System.exit(0);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Really?  Just typing in the pseudo code is sufficient effort in your mind?

Comment: @duffymo I sometimes write pseudocode as well, when I am writing. It helps me write correct and consistent code, and not forget things when I am writing them.

Comment: I write pseudocode too, but I don't think it demonstrates sufficient effort.  I also think it leads the OP away from a more OOP approach; see my answer.

Comment: You have more work to do, then.  What you've posted isn't sufficient in my opinion.  Break the problem up.  Read the file, break lines into data.  If you look at it as one big problem you'll be overwhelmed and never get anywhere.  Write a small program to read a file and build on that.

Comment: If I were your instructor, I might appreciate somebody who could think beyond exactly what I gave them.

Comment: You know, I did early on try to do more "advanced" stuff, but she didn't like it and docked me points for it.  She wants it done in an array, and output on one line per employee.... we haven't learned about tabs yet so it's going to be all strung together.  I worked on it more, have errors so it wont compile, and so I'll go in tomorrow and see if I can get in person help I guess.  I've written 6 different ways to do it but I never get it to compile completely.  Nothing I've learned so far seems to fit.   Thanks for the help you did give.

Answer (score 2):

> I must have 3 loops: One to control reading the file, one to lad the
>   data into the array, and one to do the calculations.

What I've written below might just be more gobbledygook to you now, but if you ever get past this class it might be useful to know.

Another way to look at this would be more object-oriented and better decomposition to boot: You need an object to hold the data, to perform the calculations, and render output.  How you get that data is immaterial.  It's files today; next time it might be HTTP requests.

Start with an Employee object.  I deliberately left out a lot of detail that you'll have to fill in and figure out:

```
package model;

public class Employee {
    private String name;
    private double [] salaries;

    public Employee(String name, int numSalaries) { 
        this.name = name;
        this.salaries = new double[numSalaries];
    }

    public double getMinSalary() {
        double minSalary = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        // you fill this in.
        return minSalary;
    };

    public double getMaxSalary() {
        double maxSalary = Double.MIN_VALUE;
        // you fill this in.
        return maxSalary;
    }

    public double getAveSalary() {
        public aveSalary = 0.0;
        if (this.salaries.length > 0) {
            // you fill this in.
        }
        return aveSalary;
    }
}
```

The beauty of this approach is that you can test it separately, without worrying about all the nonsense about file I/O.  Get this object right, put it aside, and then tackle the next piece.  Eventually you'll have a clean solution when you assemble all these smaller pieces together.

Test it without file I/O using JUnit:

```
package model;

public class EmployeeTest {
    @Test
    public void testGetters() {
        double [] salaries = { 10000.0, 20000.0, 30000.0, 40000.0 };
        Employee testEmployee = new Employee("John Q. Test", salaries);
        Assert.assertEquals("John Q. Test", testEmployee.getName());
        Assert.assertEquals(10000.0, testEmployee.getMinSalary(), 1.0e-3);
        Assert.assertEquals(40000.0, testEmployee.getMaxSalary(), 1.0e-3);
        Assert.assertEquals(25000.0, testEmployee.getMinSalary(), 1.0e-3);     
    }
}
```

Comment: I can see how this is much cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

The approach you would want to espouse in this situation is an object-oriented approach.  Bear in mind that objects are a representation of related data.  Consider that an `Employee` may have information about their salary, name, and what department they work in (as an example).

But that's just *one* `Employee`.  You may have *hundreds*.

Consider creating a model of an Employee.  Define what is most pertinent to one of them.  For example, they all have to have a name, and have to have a salary.

One would then elect to handle the logic of finding information about the collection of Employees - including min, max, and average salaries - *outside* of the scope of the generic Employee object.

The idea is this:

- An `Employee` knows everything about itself.
- The onus is on the developer to tie multiple Employees together.

It's possible that I don't know enough about what your problem is specifically looking for - I'm not even sure that you can use objects, which would really suck - but this is definitely a start.

---

As for your compilation errors:

- `salary` is a `double[]`.  An array holds many different values of type `double` inside of it, but a `double[]` isn't directly a `double`.  Assigning a non-array type to an array type doesn't work, from both a technical stance, and a semantic stance - you're taking something that can hold many values and trying to assign it to a container that can hold one value.

  From your code sample, you want to use a loop (with a loop variable `i`) to iterate over all elements in `salary`, and assign them some value.  Using just `salary[0]` only modifies the first element.

Comment: A List<Employee> would make a great deal of sense.

Comment: I see.  Well I cannot use the scanner utility.  I can only use basic while, for, and if-then type statements.  The instructions I was given are typed exactly as written at the top of the first question. I have worked on the code some more and I had it to print the name, and then it listed all the salaries, I don't even want to see the salaries, I just want to pick out and display the minimum, the maximum and then calculate the average and print it all on one line next to the name.